# Can't close Norton popup window when installing Shockwave player

Tags: windows, flash-player, norton-internet-security

When trying to install Adobe Shockwave Player, a popup window appears asking to install Norton Security Scan. Since there is no usable "Agree" or "OK" or whatever button to make a choice and close that popup window, I'm stuck during installation and cannot continue.

[image: adobe shockwave install screen]

All that can be done is kill installation process in Task Manager.

How can this error be resolved?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following:

Go to http://www.ninite.com and download an installer from there with only Shockwave. Run the installer. You should be able to install that, as it will bypass any annoying popup and just install Shockwave.

I am assuming you're on a Windows machine, as this will not work on more exotic OS's.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is the typical Adobe bloat-ware garbage similar to the Google Chrome install everyone misses and don't understand where Chrome came from and why it's now the default browser.

Anyway, when I ran that installer it gave me the same window. When I unselected the *"Include Norton Security Scan"* check box, the button switched to <kbd>Next</kbd>. Once clicked it finished the install.

Uncheck that box and click *"Agree"* to finish the installation. If it still installs Norton you can uninstall it manually from the control panel.

Answer (score -1):

After you uncheck the box just press Enter on your keyboard...
Hope this helps.